# How to reset user control at button press?

Tags: c#

I have this cod

```
 private void InregistrareScrapBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        verificareUserControl.Hide();

        inregstrareUserControl.Show();

        CenterPannel.Controls.Add(inregstrareUserControl);
        verificareUserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

[image]
on button press the user control from above shows.

How can I make at button press to reset from [image]
to [image]

Comment: What do you mean by `reset`?

Comment: is that related to web or desktop application?

Comment: The user control contains labels, textboxes and ddboxes that fills other labels with values. How can I make it to reset to default

Comment: @Hitesh Mistry it`s a desktop app that insert data into database.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Setting the values via code?

Comment: We don't know your form, so you need to be more specific about what parts of resetting which exact controls to which desired state you are having issues with. At this point any answer is a random guess and the question is to broad as it stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in following way:

- You can have a function called "clear()" on the usercontrol which resets all the values in the controls (eg. txtYourControlName.Text = "") and call it from parent control.
- Or just instantiate the control again in parent control, but this would be overhead.

I hope this will help. :)